# Puppet printing undef string instead of nil

Tags: puppet

I'm currently in the process of updating some legacy Puppet files to a newer version of puppet and am running into the following problem:

The hieradata for one of our server has variables that can be left undefined and still work when we generate an `env.yml` for our RoR application from an `erb` file.

Previously, this worked correctly with our `env.yml` generating those values like:

```
read_only_mode:
```

With our update to Puppet v5, the values now generate as:

```
read_only_mode: undef
```

In the `erb` template:

```
read_only_mode: <%= @data['read_only_mode'] %>
```

I'm currently trying to write a test in the Puppet file that generates the `env.yml` with the thought that the following logic should work:

```js
for ($key, value in $hieradata) {
  if ($hierdata[$key] == undef) {
    $hieradata[$key] = '' // Empty string
  }
}
```

As implemented:

```
$envdata.each |String $key, String $value| {
  if $envdata[$key] == undef {
    $envdata[$key] = ''
  }
}
```

However, this isn't working and the `undef` string is still being printed.

Does anyone have ideas as to a solution to this issue?

Comment: There are a few different issues in the question, but in general a `nil` is converted to an `undef` type, and not a String with value `undef`, so there is something happening elsewhere in the code not shown in the question to cause this implicit recast.

Comment: @MattSchuchard nothing in our code has changed from our current puppet server (running v3) to v5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up changing the Hash values using the following code:

```
$data_tuples = $data.map |$key, $value| {
  if type($value) == Undef {
    [$key, '']
  } else {
    [$key, $value]
  }
}

$data_filtered = Hash($data_tuples)
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
read_only_mode: undef
```

is going to be interpreted as a string and it's going to be passed into the template as a string, remembering that an ERB is Embedded RuBy we have to pass in something that Ruby is going to recognise as a null value and you can do this as follows.

```
read_only_mode: null
read_only_mode: Null
read_only_mode: NULL
read_only_mode: ~
read_only_mode:
```

So I'm not sure why you needed to change from

```
read_only_mode:
```

to

```
read_only_mode: undef
```

unless there is something else going on in your code, I couldn't really tell as your problem statement seemed to be missing a few bits.
Once I had my values set in hiera as above I'd then wrap the template code in an if;

```
# erb template
<% if @data != nil -%>
value2 <%= @data %>
<% end -%>
```

The class

```
# pp class file
$data = lookup(read_only_mode)

  file { '/tmp/test':
    ensure  => file,
    content => template('module2/test.erb'),
  }
```

If you're refactoring your template for Puppet 5 you might want to go the whole hogg and convert it to epp which is much easier to use and you get access to regular Puppet language functions such as `each`.

Comment: Reread the issue. The issue is the string undef is being printed when we want a blank value.